# How to handle regressors that are interchangeable

Tags: regression, predictor

I am trying to set up a multinomial logistic regression for which one of the 5 NBA players on the court at a given time end up taking a shot.

```
    OFF_P1      OFF_P2      OFF_P3      OFF_P4      OFF_P5      PLAYER_SHOT
0   6.482081    8.199627    7.034929    8.004813    5.830139    5
1   6.482081    8.199627    7.034929    8.004813    5.830139    4
2   3.821826    7.149693    9.934506    8.793994    11.039031   4
3   3.821826    7.149693    9.934506    8.793994    11.039031   4
4   3.821826    7.149693    9.934506    8.793994    11.039031   5
```

Each row has the 5 players that are playing and their respective shot attempts per 100 possessions.

The `OFF_P1 - OFF_P5` are the 5 players that were on the court, but for each row any one of the 5 players can be considered as any of `OFF_P1-OFF_P5`.

Would sorting the row so `OFF_P1` would be set to the highest value and `OFF_P5` set to the lowest value help mitigate this issue? Is this even an issue in the first place?

Comment: To me it is unclear what the `OFF_` variables represent, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: `OFF_` variables represent an individual players average shot attempts per 100 possessions in the games prior @MartinGeorgHaas

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you are trying to predict which of the five positions takes a shot; each row represents a different game; and each of the positions might be occupied by a different player from game to game?

Comment: Somewhat correct, I am trying to predict which of the five players takes a shot each row represents a different possession in a game so there can be 100s of rows from a single game.

Comment: For example, the first row in the example, there were 5 players on the court `[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5]` and P5 ended up taking the shot. When I created my data set I just used the ordering P1 to OFF_P1 etc. but I technically could have set `P5` to `OFF_P1`, `P4` to `OFF_P2` the ordering of the players for each row is arbitrary.

Comment: A clearer example might be - if each row represented 5 horses in a horse race and I was trying to predict each horses winning probability given each horses average speed in prior races. If each race could have a different set of 5 horses, I can put any of the 5 horses from a race in any of the 5 columns

Comment: Please add clarifications as an edit to the post! We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked!